# Prove or disprove the following claim for all monotonically increasing functions $f(n)$

Tags: asymptotics

Prove or disprove the following claim for all monotonically increasing functions $f(n)$.

$$f(n) = \theta ((f(\sqrt{n}))^2)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The claim is false. Assume f(n) = log n. It provides a contradiction to the claim.